# Invoke FCIV within Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, error-code, fciv

I am using the [FCIV](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533) ( Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier ) executable to automatically calculate checksums for certain files.

I want to invoke this executable within a powershell script. This is my snippet within Powershell.

```
& "Path to FCIV.exe" –add "Base Dir" -bp "Base Dir" -r –xml "Path to XML"
```

This commands basically recurses and calculates checksums for all files under "Base Dir" and then outputs into an XML file. I am able to execute this command on Powershell prompt. But when I add this line into a script and execute the script, I get this error.

```
–add\*
    Error msg  : The system cannot find the path specified.
    Error code : 3
```

I have tried everything from adding FCIV to PATH environment variable as well as providing the whole path to files.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Comment: Enclose your whole command in single quotes & ' "exe" -param "path" ... '

Comment: This did not help either.

Comment: @JanChrbolka - I was able to resolve this by trial and error. I didn't add double quotes to the parameters. - & "Path to FCIV.exe" –add Base Dir